# How to set URL anchor (hash) in servlets?

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, servlets, anchor

Simple question! Don't know why Google doesn't know the answer!

In a Java servlet, how can I set the URL anchor (hash) when returning to the user?

Comment: When returning what? A servlet typically returns a HTML page, or data as JSON or XML. It doesn't return a URL, unless it redirects. And you can add a hash to the redirect URL if you want so. It's just a String. If your goal is to change the URL of the resource that the client asked, you can't. Only the client can.

Comment: @JBNizet When returning an HTML. I want the simplest case. I am worried whether redirecting has other implications/side-effects?

Comment: As I said, you can't. The server can't do that.

Comment: Redirecting the request will not work, since it will cause a redirect loop. /someurl is the same server path as /someurl#hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL anchor is handled by the browser only and never even reaches the server (it's not part of the request).

What this means is that server-side, either in a servlet as you propose or with any other server-side technology (e.g. PHP), you **can** redirect to an URL which has the URL anchor set, but you **cannot** check if an URL anchor was provided in the request you are currently processing.

This limitation prevents you from setting the URL anchor **while keeping the rest of the URL unchanged**, because the server has no way to differentiate between the address with and without the URL anchor.

So, this, you **can do**: the canonical address to this answer is this

```
http://stackoverflow.com/a/27988314/4402557
```

but the server redirects it to this

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987762/how-to-set-url-anchor-hash-in-servlets/27988314#27988314
```

Note that the part of the URL before the anchor is not the same.

In an HTTP servlet, you can achieve this by using the `sendRedirect(String)` method of the `HTTPServletResponse` object passed to your service method, for example

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException {

    /* ... */

    response.sendRedirect("http://example.com/your/url#hash");
}
```

However, this, you **cannot do**: redirect this

```
http://example.com/some/url
```

to this

```
http://example.com/some/url#there
```

As far as the server is concerned, both are the **same address**, it cannot distinguish between them. That makes it impossible to check if the address was the first (the one without the URL anchor) and redirect conditionally if it is. Redirecting without checking will, of course, create a redirect loop.

However, depending on what it is exactly you are trying to accomplish, even if you cannot do it in your servlet, you can probably achieve it with client-side scripting (i.e. JavaScript). Have a look at the `window.location.hash` property.

Comment: Well I am not looking for reading the URL anchor received.
I would like to set the URL anchor when returning to the user.

Comment: @AliMoosavi I understand. Please have a look at my revised answer, I think it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Once I encountered a similar need.

My problem was:

I had two different forms on the same jsp page (one for registrations and one for logging in). The forms were made visible by hashes in urls, i.e. `http://myapp.com/auth#login` made login form visible and `http://myapp.com/auth#signup` made signup form visible.

I needed to show the validation errors to the user by reloading the same page, but couldn't navigate to hashes from my servlet.

Here's how I showed validation errors (jsp):

```
    <form method="post" action="authentication">
        <c:forEach items="${errorSignupMessage}" var="message">
            <div class="error-message">${message}</div>
        </c:forEach>
          ..................................
    </form>
```

and `errorSignupMessage` was the attribute I passed in through servlet

```
request.setAttribute("errorSignupMessage", array);
```

---

## The solution:

Firstly, I created the hidden field in my form that had to contain the needed attributes:

```
<input type="text" name="ACTION" class="hidden  important" value="signup" data-attr="${errorSignupMessage != null ? true : false}"/>
```

the important thing to look at is the attribute `data-attr`. As you can see, I set the boolean value on the attribute depending on actions from servlet, i.e. if the `errorSignupMessage` is `null`, than the user interacted with another form and if `errorSignupMessage` exists and is not `null`, then the current form is the one the user interacted with.

Then I went to javascript and using `window.onload` event did the data attribute detection and wrote some logic for changing the `location.hash` value.

```
var authForms = document.getElementsByClassName('important');
function changeHash() {
    for(var i = 0; i < authForms.length; ++i) {
        var form = authForms[i];

        if (form.value === 'signup' && form.getAttribute('data-attr') === 'true') {
            location.hash = '#signup';
        } else {
            location.hash = '#login';
        }
    }
}
window.onload = changeHash;
```

---

This is how I solved that. Of course, you'll need to adopt all this for your needs, but I think you still get the general idea.

Hope it was helpful!